# The performance issue on spring batch (for delete data)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch

Our team uses a Spring Batch application to periodically remove DB data. In most cases, we work with chunk-oriented jobs instead of Tasklets.

The components we use for Reader/Processor/Writer are as follows:

1. JpaPagingItemReader
2. ItemProcessor
3. RepositoryItemWriter

In the Reader, we initially read the root entity (using a pageSize/chunkSize of 1000). In the Processor, we perform operations to remove associated data using respective JpaRepositorie. Finally, in the Writer, we remove the root entity.

The problem is that the speed of this batch job is very slow. When logging in the Processor, the logs are generated quickly for the initial 400 out of 1000 pages, but after that, there is a noticeable slowdown. While the Reader is capable of reading 1000 items at once, so I think it's not a query issue.

I'm not sure why the Processor logs are slow and the batch speed decreases.

Here is our code snippet.

#### Reader

```
// omit
        val reader: JpaPagingItemReader<Group> = object : JpaPagingItemReader<Group>() {
            override fun getPage(): Int {
                return 0
            }
        }.apply {
            pageSize = batchPageSize
            setName("reader")
            setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
            setQueryString(
                "SELECT g FROM Group g " +
                        "WHERE (g.type = 'A' OR g.type IS NULL) " +
                        "   AND (g.dateLastUpdated< \'$expiredDate\' OR g.dateLastUpdated IS NULL) " +
                        "ORDER BY g.id")
        }

        return reader
    }
// omit
```

#### Processor

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    fun processor(): ItemProcessor<Group, Group> {
        return ItemProcessor { group ->
            log.info("PROCESSOR-START: DELETE EXPIRED GROUP group id {}", group.id)
            val users = userRepository.findByGroup(group)
            activityRepository.deleteByUsers(users )
            // omit
            group
        }
    }
```

#### Writer

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    fun writer(): RepositoryItemWriter<Group> {
        RepositoryItemWriter<Group>().let {
            it.setRepository(groupRepository)
            it.setMethodName("delete")
            return it
        }
    }
```

P.S. Here is processor log. The log accumulation get slower

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ONOq.png)

Initially, I suspected a query issue, but since it's a paging reader, I concluded that there is no problem with the query itself.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to write a few simple DELETE queries instead of retrieving everything, retrieving even more (which fills the 1st level cache and does dirty checking which is the cause for your performance degradation).

Comment: Something is missing here:  `SELECT g FROM Group g ...`

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, your suggestion looks nicely. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is a performance killer.  See if you can avoid testing for `OR .. IS NULL`.

After that, this 'composite' index will become quite useful for performance:

```
INDEX(type, dateLastUpdated)
```

If the framework prevents you from doing these things, can you switch to "raw SQL" or whatever?

Tips on big deletes:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig